# Can you access user edit history data through freebase data dump?

Tags: freebase, data-dump

I would like to access user edit history for freebase to see what pages were edited most often over the past couple of years and by whom. I have downloaded the freebase data dump, but I can't find an indication that it contains edit history or timestamps. Is this data part of the dump or is it somewhere else? If it is part of the dump, what subject or predicate id's would I need to search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is not currently available in the data dumps. There are currently over 2 billion facts in Freebase so publishing a history of edits would be a lot of data. There is a data dump for the [deleted triples](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data#freebase-deleted-triples) so if you combine them that would tell you which topics were edited the most but not who edited them.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way of contacting Google for this data? It would be for an academic research project at my university.